# HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync behaving different in .NET Core and Classic .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am hosting a Classic .NET WebAPI endpoint in IIS that accepts POST requests to upload a document.

I have created two console applications that will connect to the WebAPI and upload a document: One is a classic .NET (v4.6.2) console application, the other is a .NET Core console application. The code is *identical*, but the service responds differently to each. The WebAPI seems to be unable to read the request body of the .NET Core POST request, but is able to do so with the Classic .NET POST request.

Is there something I'm missing?

**WebAPI endpoint**

> http://localhost/WebApi/Library/api/Documents

```
[Route("api/Documents")]
public class DocumentsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost()]
    public void Create([FromBody] Document document)
    {
        if (document == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Posted document is null.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Document text: {document.Text}");
        }
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**.NET Core/Classic .NET console application**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api-localhost"),
        };

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/library/api/documents", new Document() { Text = "The document text" });
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The thing is this: When I attach the debugger to the WebAPI the following is outputted:

POST Request from the Classic .NET console application:

> Document text: The document text

POST Request from the .NET Core console application:

> Posted document is null.

I am at a loss at explaining the difference in behavior.

Some sprinkling of extra information:

.NET Core console application's project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "System.Net.Http": "4.3.0",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "4.3.0"

  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Classic .NET packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

From Fiddler, the raw .NET Core post:

```
POST http://localhost/library/api/documents HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: api-localhost

1c
{"Text":"The document text"}
0
```

And here's the raw Classic .NET POST:

```
POST http://localhost/library/api/documents HTTP/1.1 Accept:
application/json Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Host:
api-localhost Content-Length: 28 Expect: 100-continue Connection:
Keep-Alive

{"Text":"The document text"}
```

It seems to me that the weird "1c" and "0" might have something to do with my problem. But I don't see how/why they should even be there.

**Update: Some observations**

I also created a very basic .NET Core WebAPI end point that essentially does the same thing as the Classic .NET described up top. This proved to be able to accept the POST request from both console applications.

I also created a third console application for .NET Core where I skip using the PostAsJsonAsync and instead use PostAsync with StringContent:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost"),
        };

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var document = new Document() { Text = "The document text." };

        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        await httpClient.PostAsync("/library2/api/documents", httpContent);
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Alternating between /library/... and /library2/..., the POST request from this application is accepted by both the .NET Core and the Classic .NET WebAPIs.

**Summary**

On the server side I have two WebAPIs

- /library - Classic .NET
- /library2 - .NET Core

On the client side I have three variants of the same console applicaton:

- ConsoleApplication1 - Classic .NET using PostAsJsonAsync

  - Works fine with both WebAPIs
- ConsoleApp1 - .NET Core using PostAsJsonAsync

  - Fails with /library (Classic .NET), works fine with /library2 (.NET Core)
- ConsoleApp2 - .NET Core using PostAsync

  - Works fine with both WebAPIs

The obvious work-around here is to *never* use PostAsJsonAsync in a .NET Core client applicaton, which is a shame since it is really convenient. :(

-S

Comment: In the example above the client code isn't posting to the route defined on the controller action. Is that that what the client code actually looks like?

Comment: The easiest way to find the difference is to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: @IanGilroy:  Well spotted, but that's just my anonymization skills failing me :) I'll see about updating the sample code. However: The request does get routed to the correct controller and action, thus triggering the Debug.WriteLine statements.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Fiddler reveals some interesting differences. I'll update the OP due to the character limit in this comment field.

Comment: Could you try setting `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = false;` Should be better way of handling this in the other side, but just for testing

Comment: @Developer: Curiously, it appears that it is **PostAsJsonAsync** that sets TransferEncodingChunked = true. Setting this to false on the HttpClient object before performing the POST has no effect. However, setting TransferEncodingChunked = true before calling **PostAsync** produces the same negative result: Curious leading and trailing values in the POST body, and the Classic .NET WebAPI is unable to retrieve the posted object!

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1978292.aspx?Web+api+2+1+does+not+work+with+a+chunked+request -- here someone got this working when he downgraded web api to 5.0.0.0 _If I reinstall the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.* nuget package to 5.0.0, it works. But when those packages upgrade to 5.1 or above, it does not work._

Comment: @Developer: Downgrading to 5.0.* for the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.* family of Nuget packages does indeed fix the failing scenario. It seems to me that there are two coinciding issues: 1) The major issue is that there appears to be that the newest version of the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi does not support chunked requests. 2) The PostAsJson function defaults to using chunked requests. I guess I'll have to figure out which is the lesser evil :|

Comment: I would downgrade webapi v5.0 for to fix this. Say, you have to expose your api to someone else or for other project team, you cant ask them not to sent chunked requests :)

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/252  and https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/279 confirms the difference between both calls.

Comment: 1c is the hex length of the message `{"Text":"The document text"}` ( 0x1c = 28 bytes ), but the problem with PostAsJsonAsync is that it seems buggy because write the length (28) instead of the full protocol header sentence that should "Content-length: 28" . It happens to me today and I workaround that sending my post json message through HttpClient Send method by setting request RequestUri, Method and Content to a StringContent with serialized json like `var content = new StringContent("{}", Encoding.Default, "application/json");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying problem appears to be that the Classic .NET WebAPI fails to process chunked requests in it current newest version (v5.2.3). I'm going to assume that's a bug and as a work-around downgrade to v5.0 for the time being.

Special thanks to @Developer for helpful input.

-S

Comment: I can't find an official microsoft post about this issue, anyone know where this packages are built ? been looking in github but can't find them... 
I do think we need to file an issue... because seems like Microsoft isn't aware of this.

Comment: @L.Trabacchin - Someone did raise this on an open issue in dotnet core, I have piggy backed my comment on the same issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26233