# PostAsJsonAsync not acting as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to call an API with `PostAsJsonAsync`, but it doesn't work as I would expect.

Repo:

1. Create an ASP.NET WebAPi project (.NET Framework 4.7.2)
2. Replace the `Post` method in `ValuesController` to

   ```
   // POST api/values
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string[] array)
   {
       var suffix = array == null ? "is null" : $"has {array.Length} elements";
       var message = $"`array` {suffix}";
       return Ok(message);
   }
   ```
3. Create a console app to hit the API.

   ```
   static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
       const string url = "http://localhost:6757/api/values";
       var value = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
       var client = new HttpClient();

       var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, value);
       var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       Console.WriteLine(message);

       // Do what I think PostAsJsonAsync is essentially doing
       var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
       var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
       response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
       message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       Console.WriteLine(message);
   }
   ```
4. Run the WebApi followed by the console app

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> "`array` has 2 elements"
>
> "`array` has 2 elements"

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

> "`array` is null"
>
> "`array` has 2 elements"

So I changed the `Post` method to compare content strings at the request.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
    var value = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Ok();
}
```

They both set `value` to `["a","b"]`.

So why is `PostAsJsonAsync` not working like I think it should?

Comment: In your changed version of `Post`, look for differences in request headers between  the 2 calls. Is one setting `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and the other not? There seems to be a bug in Web API on full framework that could be applicable here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42073484/62600

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a similar issue, basically, `PostAsJsonAsync()` is serializing the `List<string>` as `"a,b"`.

I would recommend to use the same code of your example:

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

that is proven to work.