# PostAsJsonAsync posts null

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to post an object using PostAsJsonAsync, but it is always null at the receiving API. The calling code is here:

```
    public async Task UploadDocument(FileDto model)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("file/UploadDocument", model);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

The signature of the receiving code is here:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadDocument")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadDocument(FileDto document)
```

FileDto is identical in both projects and only contains one string property "FileName"

The problem is that the document is always null.

I can use PostAsync which works fine:

```
    public async Task UploadDocument(FileDto model)
    {
        string inputJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        HttpContent inputContent = new StringContent(inputJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("file/UploadDocument", inputContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

Looking at Fiddler, with the first (not working) example, the request looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:59322/api/file/UploadDocument HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:59322

28
{"FileName":"File-0000004157.jpg"}
0
```

The second (working) example looks like this in Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:59322/api/file/UploadDocument HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:59322


{"FileName":"File-0000004157.jpg"}
```

The first example appears to have added extra text - see the "28" and "0".

Where is this text coming from.  I can just go with PostAsync, but it seems a shame to add the extra code when PostAsJsonAsync does it for you.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `IActionResult` instead of `IHttpActionResult` in asp.net core

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadDocument")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocument(FileDto document)
{
    return Ok(document);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-3.0

[ASP.NET Core Web Api Error for IhttpActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029185/asp-net-core-web-api-error-for-ihttpactionresult)

Comment: Hi, Sorry, forgot to mention that that method is in a .NET Framework app.  The calling app is .NET Core

Comment: @Richard Clarke It seems no problem when I use asp.net core web api to call the asp.net web api using httpclient PostAsJsonAsync.Have you tried in a brand new project?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with PostAsJsonAsync in .net core : It returns a *content-length* of 0 causing the receiving ends to ignore the *declared empty* body.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/252

[HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync behaving different in .NET Core and Classic .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073484/httpclient-postasjsonasync-behaving-different-in-net-core-and-classic-net)

The workaround is to use... `PostAsync`